# can't figure out how to add where clause to this LINQ query

Tags: c#, mysql, linq

I'm still trying to pickup LINQ, and was wondering if anyone can shed some light on what I'm doing wrong here.  I'm pulling a bunch of rows from a database, and grouping by the ManufacturerSKU(the ManufacturerSKU has multiple rows with different ListingPrice and I get the ManufacturerSKU with the cheapest ListingPrice from the database)

```
//store the cheapest row for a ManufacturerSKU in a list
var product_result = (
    from row in dtProductListings.AsEnumerable()
    group row by row.Field<string>("ManufacturerSKU") into g
    select new Product
    {
        ManufacturerSKU = g.Key,
        ListingPrice = g.Min(x => x.Field<double>("ListingPrice")),
        Manufacturer = g.Min(z => z.Field<string>("Manufacturer")),
    }).ToList();
```

Anyway I've been trying to add a where clause to my query so I can get results between a certain date range, using the column "TimeStamp" from the mysql database.  I've tried adding

```
where row.Field< what data type even goes in here for a date time? >("TimeStamp") >= etc..
```

but I know I must be doing something wrong as it is telling me row doesn't exist in this context.  I tried adding the where clause before the group clause, after the select but haven't had any success.  Is anyone able to offer any advice please?

**(edit: TimeStamp is a datetime)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have `dateFrom` and `dateTo` variables as the boundary of the date range. Since the type of `TimeStamp` column is datetime, you should use `row.Field<DateTime>("TimeStamp")` and the where clause should be between `from` and `group` as follows

```
var dateFrom = new DateTime(2014, 11, 1);
var dateTo = new DateTime(2014, 11, 30);

var product_result = (
    from row in dtProductListings.AsEnumerable()
    where row.Field<DateTime>("TimeStamp") > dateFrom 
    && row.Field<DateTime>("TimeStamp") < dateTo
    group row by row.Field<string>("ManufacturerSKU") into g
    select new Product
    {
        ManufacturerSKU = g.Key,
        ListingPrice = g.Min(x => x.Field<double>("ListingPrice")),
        Manufacturer = g.Min(z => z.Field<string>("Manufacturer")),
    }).ToList();
```

The above code will retrieve records with `TimeStamp` between November 1, 2014 and November 30, 2014

Comment: Putting the where clause there worked great, thanks!  I seem to be having a strange issue of it not pulling some dates within the period specified, for instance DateTime(2014, 11, 16) to DateTime(2014, 11, 18) and it seems to be missing a few that are in that range..  Could it be due to the fact the database datetime column is in a different format? EG 2014-11-17 12:54:18

Comment: That's strange, it should pull records with `TimeStamp` equals `2014-11-17 12:54:18` if the range is between `DateTime(2014, 11, 16)` and `DateTime(2014, 11, 18)`. Are you sure `TimeStamp` is a datetime, not varchar?

Comment: Ah it was due to a logical error in my code, thanks again for your help LINQ is so powerful but hard to get into haha.